# MVC Webgrid Column Pointing to Array Indices - is this possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I'm playing with the MVC Webgrid in a project, pretty impressed so far, but I think I've found one restriction to it's capabilities, which I'm assuming is due to the nature of its reflection capabilities.

It seems quite alright to point at data as such:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model); //this has Model.Data - an IEnumerable list of "whatever".
grid.Columns(grid.Column("Data.SomeProperty"));
```

However you can't access a value in an array, such as:

```
grid.Columns(grid.Column("Data.SomeArray[0]"));
```

Which seems fair enough, as what I'm trying to do with this is a bit cheeky, but I just wondered if I'm missing something & this is technically possible...

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
grid.Column("ColumnName", format: @<text>@item.Data.SomeArray[0]</text>)
```

Comment: Hi @Darin - thanks, I found that too when tinkering (but +1 ofc as you are quite correct!). Only problem is sorting can't work as the cell's value as seen by the grid isn't the displayed value. Probably another question, but is there a way of defining how items are sorted or maybe I should just try and override the sort handlers in the action?